# Change locale for Google Colab

Tags: locale, google-colaboratory

I want to change the local setting (to **change the date format**) in GoogleCollab

The following works for me in JupyterNotebook but not in GoogleColab:

`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8')`

It always returns the error: **unsupported locale setting**

I have already looked at many other solutions and tried everything.
One solution to change only the time zone I have seen is this one:

```
'!rm /etc/localtime
!ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Bangkok /etc/localtime
!date
```

Comment: Any solution? I am interested in the same 'locale' but in terms of using comma as decimal separators. Similarly -- in Jupyter the line: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE.UTF-8')` worked perfectly. But not in Google Colab,

Comment: @Aleksander_B - you need the `LC_ALL` context, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2392) I was able to load german locales. However it needs to be done in two steps: Installing new, german locale. Restarting kernel and loading german locale.

**In short:**

```
import os

# Install de_DE
!/usr/share/locales/install-language-pack de_DE
!dpkg-reconfigure locales

# Restart Python process to pick up the new locales
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

**More detailed version:**
It turned out that the list of available locales is pretty short which can be checked like this:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

#  find local date time formatting on Google Colab 
local_format_str = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)
print('local_format_str on Google Colab: ', local_format_str)
print('now in Google Colab default format:', now.strftime(local_format_str))

print('Loading avaliable locales via real names...')
for real_name in set(locale.locale_alias.values()):
  try:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, real_name)
    print('success: real_name = ', real_name)
  except:
    pass

print('Loading avaliable locales via aliases...')
for alias , real_name in locale.locale_alias.items():
  try:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, alias)
    print('success: alias = ' , alias, ' , real_name = ', real_name)
  except:
    pass
```

With output:

```
local_format_str on Google Colab:  %a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y
now in Google Colab default format: Wed Dec  1 12:10:52 2021
Loading avaliable locales via real names...
success: real_name =  en_US.UTF-8
success: real_name =  C
Loading avaliable locales via aliases...
```

As we can see there is no german locale, so it needs to be installed with code:

```
import os

# Install de_DE
!/usr/share/locales/install-language-pack de_DE
!dpkg-reconfigure locales

# Restart Python process to pick up the new locales
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

giving an output:

```
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  de_DE.ISO-8859-1... done
Generation complete.
dpkg-trigger: error: must be called from a maintainer script (or with a --by-package option)

Type dpkg-trigger --help for help about this utility.
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  de_DE.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

Then we load german locale `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'german')` and the same code as at the beginning (remember about importing again packages) gives us:

```
Loading avaliable locales via real names...
success: real_name =  C
success: real_name =  en_US.UTF-8
success: real_name =  de_DE.ISO8859-1
Loading avaliable locales via aliases...
success: alias =  deutsch  , real_name =  de_DE.ISO8859-1
success: alias =  german  , real_name =  de_DE.ISO8859-1
```

and the default formatting is more German:

```
local_format_str on Google Colab:  %a %d %b %Y %T %Z
now in Google Colab default format: Mi 01 Dez 2021 12:12:03
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured this one out after a long time:

1. In `Colab`, you will have to install the desired `locale`s. You do this with:
   `!sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

   - This will prompt for a numeric input, e.g. `268` and `269` for Hungarian.
     So you enter `268 269`.
   - It will also prompt for the `default locale`, after installation. Here you will need to **select** your desired custom `locale`. This time, it is a numeric selection out of `3-5` options, depending, on how many have you selected at the previous step. In my case, I have selected `3`, and the default `locale` became `hu_HU`.
2. You need to restart the `Colab` runtime: `Ctrl + M` then `.`
3. You need to activate the `locale`:
   `import locale`
   `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'hu_HU')` <- make sure you do it for the `LC_ALL` context.
4. The custom `locale` is now ready to use with `pandas`:
   `pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01').day_name()` returns `Friday`, but
   `pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01').day_name('hu_HU')` returns `Péntek`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't successful using German locale on Google Colab, but desired formatting could be obtained as a combination of overriding `locale` for decimal separator and date formatting.

German formatting rules can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-7/index.html).

For custom string formatting nice cheatsheet is [here](https://strftime.org/).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import locale

german_format_str_full = '%Y-%m-%d, %H.%M Uhr'
german_format_str_date = '%Y-%m-%d'

# genereting plot data, xs are dates with not obvious step
xs = np.arange(datetime(year=2021, month=11, day=28, hour=23, minute=59, second=59),
               datetime(year=2021, month=12, day=6, hour=23, minute=59, second=59),
               timedelta(hours=5,minutes=47,seconds=27))
ys = np.sin(np.arange(0,len(xs),1)) # whatever

# use overwritten locale for comma as decimal point -- German formatting
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True
locale._override_localeconv["decimal_point"]= ','

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
ax.plot(xs,ys, 'o-')

# set formatting string using mdates from matplotlib
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(german_format_str_date))

# rotate formatted ticks or use autoformat 'fig.autofmt_xdate()'
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.title('Google Colab plot with German locale style')
plt.show()
```

It gives me this plot:

[image: Google Colab matplotlib plot with German locale style]

If you need to check how formatting settings look like on your machine you can use `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)`. For example:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

#  find local date time formatting on Google Colab 
local_format_str = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)
print('local_format_str on Google Colab: ', local_format_str)
print('now in Google Colab default format:', now.strftime(local_format_str))

german_format_str_full = '%Y-%m-%d, %H.%M Uhr'
german_format_str_date = '%Y-%m-%d'
print('now in German format, full:',now.strftime(german_format_str_full))
print('now in German format, only date:',now.strftime(german_format_str_date))

ridiculous_format = '%Y->%m-->%d'
print('now ridiculous_format:',now.strftime(ridiculous_format))
```